# error while installing monero wallet on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/monero_0.17.2.0+~0+20200826-1ubuntu4_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/monero-blockchain-ancestry', which is also in package monero-gui 0.18.1.2-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/monero_0.17.2.0+~0+20200826-1ubuntu4_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```